# C++ function overload resolution from inside a function template depends on whether the function is defined in a namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces, overloading, argument-dependent-lookup, template-instantiation

The following code compiles fine:

```
#include <cstdio>

//namespace N {
    void f( int x ) { printf( "f( int ) called\n" ); }
    void f( double x ) { printf( "f( double ) called\n" ); }
//}

template < typename T > inline void g( const T& t ) {
//    N::f( t );
    f( t ); }

struct X {};
//namespace N {
    void f( const X& x ) { printf( "f( const X& ) called\n" ); }
//}

int main() {
    g( 1 );
    g( 1.2 );
    g( X{} );
}
```

But if I define f()s inside a namespace, e.g. by uncommenting the above code, then the compiler generates an error:

```
t.cpp:11:5: error: no matching function for call to 'f'
    N::f( t );
    ^~~~
t.cpp:25:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'g<X>' requested here
    g( X{} );
    ^
t.cpp:4:10: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const X' to 'int' for 1st argument
    void f( int x ) { printf( "f( int ) called\n" ); }
         ^
t.cpp:5:10: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const X' to 'double' for 1st argument
    void f( double x ) { printf( "f( double ) called\n" ); }
         ^
```

Why is that?

Comment: Sidenote: `inline` on a template does effectively nothing

Answer (score 3):

When you have `N::f(t)`, the compiler will only find functions that are members of the namespace `N` *and* that have been declared prior to the point of use, so it won't find the overload that takes `X`.

When you have `f(t)`, because the function call is *unqualified*, [argument-dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) occurs, and as a special rule, argument-dependent lookup of a dependent name within a template will also find functions in the associated namespaces that were declared before the point of instantiation (even if they were declared *after* the point of use). When `T` is the type `X`, which was declared in the global scope, the global namespace is an associated namespace, which means that argument-dependent lookup can find functions in the global namespace that were declared either before or after the point of use, as long as they were declared before the point of instantiation. The point of instantiation for `g<X>` is actually at the end of `main` (because the call to `g<X>` occurs inside `main`), which means that all three overloads of `f` can be found by argument-dependent lookup while instantiating `g<X>`.

This special lookup rule for argument-dependent lookup is necessary for template libraries to function. Consider for example `std::sort`, which is defined inside `<algorithm>` somewhere and (typically) included into your program near the beginning. You might need to sort an array of a user-defined type `X`, which has an overloaded `operator<`. Typically, the declaration of `X` and its `operator<` will be after the `#include <algorithm>` directive and therefore after the definition of `std::sort`. However, we still expect that when `std::sort` is called to sort `X`s, it will be able to use the `operator<` for `X` even though the latter was declared *after* the former's definition.